# Creating a Square Matrix

Tags: java, matrix

Hello can someone please help me, I'm trying to do a square matrix in java with this format:

```
1 | 6 | 7 | 12
2 | 5 | 8 | 11
3 | 4 | 9 | 10
```

What I want is that the code generates a table with the size specified by the user and prints it with the given format above.

I thought I already finished it but when I input an odd number as a COLUMN, it will always add another column. So, for example,
**Input:**I entered `3` as the `no. of columns`, 
**Output:**It will print four (`4`) columns.

Here is my code (written in java):

```
System.out.print("Enter Number(s) of ROW: ");

int numRow = in.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Number(s) of COLUMN: ");

int numCol = in.nextInt();
int [][] Table = new int[numRow][numCol];
int ctr=0;

for(int row=0; row<numRow; row++) 
{
        for(int col=0; col<numCol; col++)
        {
                Table[row][col]= (col*numRow)+row+1;
                System.out.print(Table[row][col]+"\t");

                for(int i=col+1; i<=numRow; i++)
                {   
                    ctr=(numRow-1)-row;
                    Table[row][col]= (i*numRow)+ctr+1;
                    System.out.print(Table[row][col]+"\t"); 
                    i=numRow;
                }
                col++;               
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I'm using java, I'm sorry I wasn't able to specify  that a while ago. ✌️

Comment: Is it working with even numbers? I don't think so

Comment: Uhhh, yeah its not. Just tried it haha. Sorry if I'm being too ignorant about programming.  I'm just new in this field. 

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number(s) of ROW: ");

    int numRow = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Number(s) of COLUMN: ");

    int numCol = in.nextInt();

    int [][] Table = new int[numRow][numCol];

    int ctr=0;

    for(int row=0; row<numRow; row++) 
    {
            for(int col=0; col<numCol; col++)
            {
                if(col%2 == 0){Table[row][col] = (col * numRow +1 )+ row;}
                else{Table[row][col] = (numRow * (col + 1))- row;}
            }
    }
        for(int row=0; row<numRow; row++) 
    {
            for(int col=0; col<numCol; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(Table[row][col] +"|");
            }
            System.out.println("");
    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Not only did it do what I wanted but also fixes some of my problems I wasn't able to include in the description. Cheers to you my friend, thank you so muchhh ❤️❤️

Answer (score 0):

As other answers, your problem come from the 3rd for loop. But for more clearly, I split your work into 2 parts, they are building and displaying.

Build your matrix first.

```
int value = 1;
for(int col=0; col<numCol; col++) 
{
        if(col%1==1){ 
            for(int row=0; row<numRow; row++)
            {
                Table[row][col] = value+numRow-row;
            } 
            value = table[0][col]+1;
        }
        else{
            for(int row=0; row<numRow; row++)
            {
                Table[row][col] = value++;
            } 
        }  
}
```

Then display your matrix as the format that you expect.

```
for(int i = 0;i<numRow;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<numCol;j++)
    System.out.print(Table[i][j]);
    if(j==numCol-1) System.out.print("\n");
    else System.out.print("|");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<` instead of `<=` in your 3rd loop:

```
for (int i = col + 1; i < numCol; i++) {
    ctr = (numRow - 1) - row;
    Table[row][col] = (i * numRow) + ctr + 1;
    System.out.print(Table[row][col] + "\t");
    i = numRow;
}
```

Comment: @Makoy Most welcome, you can accept this answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from this :
`for(int i=col+1; i<=numRow; i++)`
You are executing your loop with i inferior or **equal** to numRow, meaning that when you use the instruction to set your cell value : `Table[row][col]= (i*numRow)+ctr+1`
if your maximum column number is 3, it will fill Table[row][3], as arrays index begins at 0, it will add a fourth column.